# How do I make my website available via IPV6 under an AWS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-aws, ipv6, load-balance

What do I need to do to make my website available under IPV6?  My site is running on Amazon Web Services (AWS) behind a load balancer.   I just saw that [Amazon has announced support elastic load balancers via IPV6](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/01/announcing-internet-protocol-version-6-ipv6-support-for-elastic-load-balancing-in-amazon-virtual-private-cloud-vpc/).

What settings do I need to enable at Amazon?   What DNS changes do I need to make?   How can I test my site to ensure it is working?

Comment: You might have already found the answer to this question, but does this help at all? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ipv6-support-for-ec2-instances-in-virtual-private-clouds/

As long as the VPC is set with an IPV6 block, you should be able to select the "dual-stack" option on your load-balancer. For testing, I normally just use the `curl -6` method for checking for IPV6 availability, example: `curl -6 https://www.google.com`, and `nslookup -query=AAAA` to confirm IPV6 DNS responses, example: `nslookup -query=AAAA www.google.com`.

Comment: This should be described on [Getting Started with Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-getting-started.html). Specifically for IPv6 support you can refer to [Application Load Balancers, section IP Address Type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#ip-address-type).

Answer (score 1):

I always save my steps in a text editor, here's what I put but you can probably find AWS docs super easily by Googling your question. Probably the same thing.

Run the following command replacing the values wrapped in carrots with your information:

```
aws elbv2 set-ip-address-type --load-balancer-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:<us-east-example>:<some-numbers>:loadbalancer/app/the-load-balancer/<random-string> --ip-address-type dualstack
```

Now update the dns record for the load balancer

```
dualstack.name-<numbers>.region.elb.amazonaws.com
```

With this IPv4 requests will resolve A, and IPv6 will resolve AAAA.

### Dualstack Requirements (from AWS)

You can set the IP address type when you create the load balancer and update it at any time. Note that an existing internal Application Load Balancer can't be updated to dualstack mode. You must recreate the Application Load Balancer and configure it as dualstack.

- **VPCs** and **subnets** that you specify for the load balancer must have associated **IPv6 CIDR blocks**.
- The route tables for the load balancer subnets must route IPv6 traffic.
- The security groups for the load balancer must allow IPv6 traffic.
- The network ACLs for the load balancer subnets must allow IPv6 traffic.

### Associate an IPv6 CIDR block with a VPC

```
aws ec2 associate-vpc-cidr-block \
    --amazon-provided-ipv6-cidr-block \
    --ipv6-cidr-block-network-border-group <region>  \
    --vpc-id vpc-<example-vpc>
```

Comment: That doesn't sound too bad.  Basically "enable dualstack then put in AAAA records."   I still don't know how I would test that my site is available over IPV6 though.  My ISP at home is still IPV4 only.

Comment: I tried to implement this but I got the error "Selected subnets must have the CIDR block required by the IP address type." It looks like I need to change settings on my subnets or maybe create new subnets.  I don't see anything obvious for enabling IPV6 CIDR blocks in my existing subnets.  Do you know what I have to do for that?

Comment: I found it.  In each subnet there is an "Actions" drop down with a menu item for "Edit IPv6 CIDRs".   I needed to add a CIDR there and assign it a hexidecimal final value (like `01` for my first subnet and then `02`) for my second subnet.

Comment: Can I edit your answer to add some details?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Go for it. Good looks testing this out.

Comment: I found https://screenshots.page/ which will produce screenshots of your site over both IPv4 and IPv6.  I think that would be sufficient to let me know it is working.  So for no screenshot available for IPv6 so not everything is working yet.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller So VPCs are going to have to do that too

Comment: I actually had some info about VPC if you can validate that too I don't have an env to test any of this in right now.

Comment: At this point I have the load balancer, VPC, subnet, and route table with IPv6.  On to the security group and ACL.  :)

Comment: I was thinking that the load balance could be configured to listen on the WAN to IPv6 and proxy requests to my servers over IPv4 on the LAN.  However, it is unclear from the documentation whether that is actually possible.  I don't have IPv6 running on any of my ec2 instances, and I think that may be preventing things from working.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah idk about that. I'd ask Patrick Mevzek. To confirm, this is on ostermiller.org right? That's validating ipv6 with https://ipv6-test.com/